# Transfer data to another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

How I can do this in PL/SQL? I tried but I have some errors.

---

1. `select * from account`
2. print highest BALANCE and STATUS = 'avilable'
3. insert  highest BALANCE and STATUS = 'locked' to `acc_locked`  table

---

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR T IS
        SELECT CUST_ID,A_NO ,TYPE, BALANCE,STATUS
        FROM   ACCOUNT 
        where  STATUS=('نشط')
        order by BALANCE desc;

    CURSOR D IS
        SELECT CUST_ID,A_NO ,TYPE, BALANCE,STATUS
        FROM   ACC_LOCKED 
        order by BALANCE desc;

    ci  ACC_LOCKED.CUST_ID%TYPE;
    an  ACCOUNT.A_NO%TYPE;
    ty  ACCOUNT.TYPE%TYPE;
    ba  ACCOUNT.BALANCE%TYPE;
    st  ACCOUNT.STATUS%TYPE;

BEGIN
    OPEN T ;

    FOR p IN 1..3 LOOP
        FETCH T INTO ci  , an  ,ty  , ba  ,st  ;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( ci  ||'    '|| an||'    '||ty||'    '||ba ||'    '||st);
    END LOOP ;

    CLOSE T ;

    INSERT INTO ACC_LOCKED (CUST_ID,A_NO ,TYPE, BALANCE,STATUS)
    select CUST_ID,A_NO ,TYPE, BALANCE,STATUS 
    from   ACCOUNT
    where  STATUS=('موقوف')
    order by BALANCE desc;
END;
```

Comment: *I tried but I have some errors!...* what error? and what have you tried?

Comment: What is your tables structure?

Comment: table sturcture CUST_ID  A_NO TYPE BALANCE STATUS

Comment: Edit your question rather than answer in comments. Show what you have tried, the schema of the two tables, etc. __In your question__

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 steps to do, what you also listed. 
 
Step 1 = That cursor you made, cursor 'T', look okey. 
 
Step 2 = Loop through cursor 'T', look okey. 
Step 3 = Doesn't work, becasue you already closed your cursor 'T'.

Maybe this more simplefied example will give you an idea:

```
DECLARE
        CURSOR T IS 
               SELECT  CUST_ID,A_NO ,TYPE, BALANCE,STATUS
               FROM    ACCOUNT 
               WHERE   STATUS='Available'
               ORDER BY BALANCE DESC;
BEGIN
        FOR recT IN T LOOP
                -- You can print every value form cursor T this way.
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(recT.Cust_Id);

                --Insert in table, add every column to insert here. 
                INSERT INTO Acc_Locked (Cust_Id, A_No)
                VALUES(recT.Cust_Id, recT.A_No);
        END LOOP;

        -- Save what you just inserted. 
        COMMIT;
END;
```